# Simple Github commit not working (trying to add an image to my public image folder)

Tags: git, ssh, github, git-commit, git-add

So i'm trying to do something i know is simple but its causing me some headaches.  I am just trying to get an image from my app (im using MacFusion to ssh to our app vs having it on my machine locally).  I basically dragged an image into the public/images folder along w/ some other html/css changes & then committed everything using git commit -a -m "comment about my commit here"...

I then pushed to github

So i thought that wouldve automatically added the image to the public/images folder in github (& on our server), but it didn't.  all the other html & style changes went through but the image didn't show up in the public/images folder when i look in github.

I"m sure this is something dumb i'm overlooking but could really use a quick reason this is happening & instruction on how to get that one image file to the public/images folder in github.

thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the file is currently untracked by Git!

You must first add the file for git to track it.
i.e.

```
git add filename.jpg
```

Two useful commands include:

To list all files currently tracked in this git repository, use:

```
git ls-files
```

To see if any files are currently untracked in your current directory, simply run

```
git status
```

A pretty good cheatsheat of git commands can be found here:
https://github.com/AlexZeitler/gitcheatsheet/blob/master/gitcheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 3):

`git commit -a` doesn't add new files. It just commits changes to already tracked file.

Try doing a `git add .` .Or add the files explicitly and commit and push.

Use git status to see whether the files were added or not.